# Vim normal editing in Visual line not working as expected?

Tags: vim

So this is the first time i am experimenting around visual line editing in vim. I have a couple of words as following

```
cat
dog
```

and i want to surround them with brackets (without using surround.vim) for learning. The commands that i use after visual selection is as follows

```
:'<,'>norm 0i(<esc>$a)
```

and also

```
:'<,'>norm 0i(<C-v><esc>$a)
```

The problem is that vim seems to print out  as well and the output i get is

```
(<esc>$a)cat
(<esc>$a)dog
```

Any hint to where i might be going wrong will be greatly appreciated.

> Also worth noting that i am running vim using `vim -u NONE` so vimrc file doesn't get loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:normal` command does not parse special characters. As you may have guessed, `<esc>` is inserted literally as five different characters.

You will need to wrap it in `:execute` with an escape on those special characters:

```
:exe "'<,'>norm 0i(\<esc>$a)"
```

Alternative ways of doing this (using the full buffer range `%`):

1. `:exe "%norm I(\eA)"` - an alternative way of writing the esc character
2. `:%norm I(^[A)` - where `^[` is ctrl-v and then esc, to insert a literal esc character which doesn’t need to be parsed.
3. `:%s/.*/(&)`

Comment: tl;dr: `<C-v><esc>` were meant to be two keys, not ten. :)

Comment: I was actually looking over the method 2 that you wrote. Thank's for the elaborate explanation. That did clear up my concepts